# Angular 2 template data binding by value or reference

Tags: angular, angular2-template

If a parent component passing an object to a child component

```
<child-component [someValue]="someObject"></child-component>
```

If the child component modify the `someObject`, will this change be reflected in the parent component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- By value for primitive types `number`, `string`, `boolean`
- By reference of objects
  when an object is passed changes done by the receiver will take effect on the sender as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Here is a little Plunk that tests passing objects: http://plnkr.co/edit/tfRrifM8BLDHkFCACRUL?p=preview

Comment: @user2904713 http://plnkr.co/edit/5yZFCam1tDV0yXbiQ2Dl?p=preview Plunkr showing that simple values does not reflect on the parent.